# Python bool conversion to C++ (pybind11)

Tags: c++, c++11, pybind11

I am attempting to convert a python bool to a C++ bool so that it can be used for comparison, but have not been able to successfully get it to.

Here is the code that I have so far (commented out previous trials kept for reference). Any help would be greatly appreciated. So far it prints "True" and "False" when it should, but I cannot get it to evaluate correctly in a C++ if statement.

```
py::object mwparser = py::module::import("mwparserfromhell");
py::object code = mwparser.attr("parse")(py::str(text));
py::object filtered = code.attr("filter_templates")();

for(auto temp : filtered) {
    //auto type = template_figure_type(temp.attr("name"));
    auto type = template_figure_type(py::str(temp.attr("name")));
   // py::print("G ");
    //py::print(type);
 //   auto type = "";
    if(type != ""){
        try {
            //list.append(type);
            //return list;
            //py::print(py::str(type));

            py::object f = temp.attr("has")("link");
            py::print(py::str(f)); //displays "True" and "False" when it should
            //PyObject *t = Py_True;
           // int tr = PyObject_IsTrue(f);

           // if(py::str(f) == py::str("False")) {
            if(py::str(f).is(py::str("True"))) {
            //if(temp.attr("has")("link")) {
            //if(py::str(f) == py::str("True")){
           // if(0){
                temp.attr("remove")("link");
                bContent_changed = true;
                list.append(temp);
            }
            else {
                py::print("NO");
            }
        } catch (std::domain_error) {
            throw std::domain_error("");
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

```
if(f == Py_True){
```

appears to work, but is deprecated. When I attempt to use the suggested "f.is(Py_True)" it produces the error `error: reference to type 'const
      pybind11::detail::object_api<pybind11::handle>' could not bind to an
      rvalue of type 'PyObject *' (aka '_object *')
            if(f.is(Py_True)){
                    ^~~~~~~`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this can be resolved via the following change to the above code snippet

```
f.is(Py_True)
```

should be

```
if(py::str(f).is(py::str(Py_True)))
```

Hopefully this helps others who might have the same question. It is important to note that, while deprecated, the '==' comparison (f == Py_True) **still works** (for the time being).

For those curious the (functioning) updated code is as follows:

```
py::object mwparser = py::module::import("mwparserfromhell");
py::object code = mwparser.attr("parse")(py::str(text));
py::object filtered = code.attr("filter_templates")();

for(auto temp : filtered) {
    auto type = template_figure_type(py::str(temp.attr("name")));
    if(type != ""){
        try {

            py::object f = temp.attr("has")("link");
            py::print(py::str(f)); //displays "True" and "False" when it should
              if(py::str(f).is(py::str(Py_True))){
                temp.attr("remove")("link");
                bContent_changed = true;
                list.append(temp);
            }
            else {
                py::print("NO");
            }
        } catch (std::domain_error) {
            throw std::domain_error("");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this function

int PyBool_Check(PyObject *o)
Return true if o is of type PyBool_Type.